# I cannot kill crond - trying to stop cron service

Tags: cron, kill, start-stop-daemon

This is frustrating, I try:

```
service crond status
```

And get this:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  crond.service
crond.service - Command Scheduler
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2015-06-25 07:44:35 UTC; 1 months 21 days ago
Main PID: 2557 (crond)
CGroup: /system.slice/crond.service
└─2557 /usr/sbin/crond -n

Aug 14 21:18:37 li958-202.members.linode.com crond[2557]: 2015-08-14 21:18:37 1ZQMLV-0004ER-HX User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the neve...ers list
Aug 14 21:18:37 li958-202.members.linode.com crond[2557]: 2015-08-14 21:18:37 1ZQMN3-0004ST-Nr User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the neve...ers list
Aug 15 21:18:19 li958-202.members.linode.com crond[2557]: 2015-08-15 21:18:19 1ZQip4-0005iq-BH User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the neve...ers list
Aug 15 21:18:19 li958-202.members.linode.com crond[2557]: 2015-08-15 21:18:19 1ZQiqJ-0005va-CF User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the neve...ers list
Aug 16 00:35:01 li958-202.members.linode.com crond[2557]: (CRON) OPENDIR FAILED (/var/spool/cron): No such file or directory
Aug 16 01:49:57 li958-202.members.linode.com systemd[1]: Started Command Scheduler.
Aug 16 01:50:09 li958-202.members.linode.com systemd[1]: Started Command Scheduler.
Aug 16 02:08:01 li958-202.members.linode.com crond[2557]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Aug 16 02:09:01 li958-202.members.linode.com crond[2557]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Then I have tried all these per searching on SO and elsewhere:

```
kill -1 2557
kill -HUP 2557
service crond stop
```

**NOTHING** works.  Can anyone help with this?

Comment: After you use `service crond stop` what does the logs say?

Comment: I do not know where the logs are located on my machine.  I tried:
`grep CRON /var/log/messages` - no success.  Where is cron logging?

Comment: Another alternative is kill -15 2557 and only resort to kill -9 2557 if that failed.

Comment: Is there a real reason for actually wanting to stop the cron daemon, ever?

Answer (score 1):

`kill -1` is a command that will send a SIGHUP signal, meaning all processes with a pid greater than 1 are signaled.

What you need is `kill -9 2557`. The `-9` argument sends a SIGKILL signal to the desired process which ensures that it is killed.

Other alternatives if your system has the programs installed:

```
pkill crond
killall crond
```

Comment: `kill -1` sends `SIGHUP` - it doesn't do any lookup of users.

Comment: @DarkHeart, you are right. I was reading something on the kill AIX man page and I read the wrong entry. I am editing it now.

Comment: You are right about `-9` but still not quite there on the first statement. kill will only send signals to listed processes.

Comment: kill sends TERM by default, not HUP.

Answer (score 0):

According to the first line of the output you get ("`redirecting to...`"), you're using systemd, so many of the old SysV commands will not work.

Use `systemctl` to manage systemd services.

The command you need to issue to stop `cron`, would be: `systemctl stop crond.service`.
If you want to dsable it, do: `systemctl disable crond.service`.

For futher information on how to manage systemd units, see `man systemctl`.